# Youtube does not open with chrome, shows logo only

Tags: google-chrome, youtube

Couple of days youtube does not open properly on chrome, everything else works just fine. Trying to open youtube with chrome - looks like this (screenshot) Youtube still opens with firefox. What to do?

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rjHiu.jpg)

Comment: Have you tried clearing cookies and cache?

Comment: Does anything happen if you disable all of your extensions? What about using incognito mode?

Comment: Look for errors in the developer console

Comment: Have you tried reloading with F5?

Answer (score 0):

Google seems to have outdone itself with this one.
Although I've seen people report that they managed to fix it by clearing caches and reinstalling Chrome this issue seems to be caused by coding in Chrome:

If googles advertisements are blocked chrome refuses to load more than the logo. I had no issues with other browsers opening up the youtube website only in Chrome.

I've got a list of add sites my firewall is blocking and the moment I created an exception rule for a test machine Chrome was able to load the website. Disabling the test rule hence blocking advertisements lead to Chrome not being able to display the youtube page again.

Chances are that an add-blocker plugin will have the same effect.